# Q:AMPL syntax error:How to write a formula in the definition of a variable

Tags: algorithm, optimization, ampl

**I am super new in AMPL, and my optimization is to minimize I(interference power) and maxmize P(signal power), and meanwhile watch the rita(data rate), because data's equation is Nonlinear, so I didn't put it in constraints,because I must use cplex to solve, so I put it in the definition of rita, but there is an error in my code, it shows :syntax error in "context:   >>> { <<< k in K, d in D,m in M}p[k,d,m] * gmk[m,k] /({k in K, d in D,m in M}I[k,d,m] + rou);" ,could you tell me what should I do to modify it? Thank you very much!**

```
set M;
set K;
set D;
param Pmax;
param rmin;
param rou;
param x_k {s in K} :=Uniform (0, 1000);
param y_k {s in K} :=Uniform (0, 1000);
param x_b{M};
param y_b{M};
param R1{i in M, t in K} =
  sqrt((x_b[i] - x_k[t])^2 + (y_b[i]-y_k[t])^2);
param gmk{i in M, t in K} =
   103.8 + 20.9 *log10(R1[i,t]/1000);
param R2{i in K, t in K} =
   sqrt((x_k[i] - x_k[t])^2 + (y_k[i]-y_k[t])^2);
param gjk{j in K, k in K:j<>k} =
   if R2[j,k] <=50 then 98.45 + 20*log10(R2[j,k]/1000)
      else 55.28 + 40*log10(R2[j,k]);
param R4{i in M, t in M} =
     sqrt((x_b[i] - x_b[t])^2 + (y_b[i]-y_b[t])^2);
param gnm{i in M, t in M:i<>t} =
     40*log10(R4[i,t]/1000) + 169.36;
var beta{M,D};
var p{K,D,M};
var I{K,D,M};
var rita{k in K, d in D,m in M} = 
{k in K, d in D,m in M}p[k,d,m] * gmk[m,k] /({k in K, d in D,m in M}I[k,d,m] + rou);

minimize total: (sum{k in K, d in D,m in M} I[k,d,m]) - (sum {m in M,k in K, d in D}p[k,d,m])  ;

subject to C1: sum{k in K, d in D,m in M} p[k,d,m] <= Pmax;

subject to C2{k in K,d in D,m in M}: p[k,d,m] >= 0;

subject to C3{k in K, d in D,m in M}: rita[k,d,m] >= rmin;

subject to C4{d in D,m in M}: sum{k in K} p[k,d,m] >= beta[m,d];

subject to C5{d in D,m in M}: sum{k in K} p[k,d,m] <= 1000 * beta[m,d];

subject to C6{m in M}: sum{d in D} beta[m,d] = 1;


subject to cal1{k in K, m in M}: I[k,1,m] = sum{j in K} p[j,1,m] * gmk[m,j] + sum{j in K:j<>k} p[j,2,m] * gjk[j,k];

subject to cal2{k in K, m in M,n in M:m<>n}: I[k,2,m] = sum{j in K} p[j,2,m] * gmk[m,j] + sum{j in K} p[j,1,m] * gnm[n,m];
```

Answer (score 0):

The declaration of the `rita` variable collection is incorrect. The first part, where you declare the collection with `var rita{k in K, d in D,m in M}`, is ok. This says that you have a 3D variable collection indexed over all triplets (k,d,m).

However, the defining expression at the right side of the equal sign, is not valid AMPL syntax. I don't know what math expression you were trying to implement, but the two occurrences of `{k in K, d in D,m in M}` in the expression don't mean anything in AMPL. That is an indexing expression, but what for? You don't have a `sum`, or `prod`, or anything that requires that indexing expression.

Maybe all you need is to remove this indexing expression, resulting in this declaration statement:

```
var rita{k in K, d in D,m in M} = p[k,d,m] * gmk[m,k] / (I[k,d,m] + rou);
```

But then again, I don't know what expression you are trying to implement.

If you are new to AMPL, I recommend reading some introductory material, such as this https://pifop.com/help/ampl_programs.html that I've written.